# MPV player auto installed ,checked system logs

Tags: youtube-dl

I installed youtube-dl using pip and the video opened in mpv player which i did not install . I checked the system logs , and  it showed the following:

```
    : As-WARNING **: failed to rescan: Failed to parse /usr/share/applications/mpv.desktop.dpkg-new file: cannot process file of type text/plain
```

note :  it was installed today ,september 19 ,is it possible that it might have been installed with youtube-dl?
i used the following commands to install yt-dl

```
    wget -O - https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl >/dev/null
```

sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
was unsuccessful , therefor installed it via pip

```
    sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
    sudo easy_install pip
    sudo pip install --upgrade youtube-dl
```

does yt-dl install mpv on its own ?

Comment: I know that `pip` did not install it, check the `apt` logs: `grep mpv /var/log/apt/history.log` at least not when you where installing `youtube-dl`

Answer (score 0):

> does yt-dl install mpv on its own ?

No, you installed it on its own or as a dependency of another package. You can list the package dependencies for it with the `apt-cache depends` command, like this:

```
tom@desktop:~$ apt-cache depends youtube-dl 
youtube-dl
  Depends: python-pkg-resources
  Depends: <python:any>
    python:i386
    python
  Depends: <python:any>
    python:i386
    python
 |Recommends: aria2
 |Recommends: wget
    wget:i386
  Recommends: curl
    curl:i386
 |Recommends: ffmpeg
    ffmpeg:i386
  Recommends: libav-tools
 |Recommends: mpv
    mpv:i386
 |Recommends: mplayer
    mplayer:i386
  Recommends: mplayer2
  Recommends: rtmpdump
```

mpv is listed only as a recommendation, and not as a dependency. If you install youtube-dl and accept the default choices, mpv will not be installed.

If you did not install it on its own, you can check the "reverse dependencies" for mpv with the command `apt-cache rdepends mpv`, to see what did install it as a dependency (I think this assumes that original package must be installed still, not 100% sure though). If you don't see anything there that you need to keep, you may safely remove the mpv package.

For completeness, you can remove all unnecessary dependencies system-wide with the command `sudo apt autoremove`.